# Verify credentials with kerberos python

Tags: python, kerberos

I'm working on a project for university where I have to verify credentials as a last step. I should verify if those credentials are valid and I don't have to connect to any service. I was looking for a tutorial or documentation which could help me set this up but I didn't find any. Most tutorials required a token and not just username and password.

What I'm looking for is a hint how I can do this or a documentation where I can find how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I'm using Ubuntu Server 18.04 and building it inside of a docker container.

Comment: You need to write a bit more. Windows or Unix-like?

Comment: I'm working on a Ubuntu Server 18.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are looking for the [`python-gssapi`](https://pythonhosted.org/gssapi/basic-tutorial.html) package. It will perfectly accept your security context and verify the peer. Use pip to install, read the documentation and you are done.